FilamentPHP Panel Providers Not Displaying for Other Roles (Except super_admin)
I've encountered an issue with FilamentPHP while working with panel providers. Following the documentation, I used php artisan make:filament-panel user to generate a panel for managing users. I've also created a new user with the role user. However, when attempting to access the URL /user, I receive a 403 error. Interestingly, if I access the URL directly from super_admin, the panel displays as expected.
Here's a summary of my setup:
I've generated a Filament panel for managing users using the command php artisan make:filament-panel user.
I've created a new user with the role user using the default authentication system.
The user role should have access to the /user URL to manage users.
Despite following the documentation and ensuring that the user role is correctly assigned, I'm unable to access the /user URL with a non-super_admin role.
I've checked my code and reviewed the documentation, but I'm unable to identify why this issue is occurring. Any assistance or suggestions on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
